# Swal.fire when click text in Javascript (Sweetalert)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, sweetalert2

I want to make appear a window promp with sweetalert (swal.fire) when i click a text. How do if statements and window prompt work on this library? After this point, you can appreciate that i'm new in this programming world.

After that, i would like to asign a value to that input and verify if the answer is correct or not.

`<td class="gases" title="Hidrógeno" id="H">H</td>` This is the element i want to click

```
Swal.fire({
title:'¿Cuál es el elemento?',
text: 'Introduce el nombre aquí',
input: 'text',
inputPlaceholder: 'Nombre', })
```

This is the prompt i want to appear when i cliked that element. When the button 'OK' is clicked, want to verify if the name introduced is correct or not...:

```
if (name === hidrógeno) {
     Swal.fire ('Correct!', 'You got the answer right!', 'success') }

else {
     Swal.fire ('Incorrect...', 'You failed!', 'error') }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First attach a click event listener to your text that you want to be clickable. You can do this by grabbing your element using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and its class name, and then adding a click event handler to it with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(".gases");

elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // callback function
});
```

Inside of the callback function to addEventListener, you can open your sweetalert question popup using `Swal.fire()`. This method returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which resolves to the text entered by the user. To grab the resolved value from this promise, you can attach a `.then()` and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the entered text from the arguments:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(".gases");
elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Cuál es el elemento?',
    text: 'Introduce el nombre aquí',
    input: 'text',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Nombre',
  }).then(({value}) => {
    if (value === "hidrógeno") {
      Swal.fire('Correct!', 'You got the answer right!', 'success')
    } else {
      Swal.fire('Incorrect...', 'You failed!', 'error')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.16/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gases" title="Hidrógeno" id="H">Click</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```